# When invoking js.exec in Geb/Spock, the exec method is flagged as 'null'

Tags: geb

I am creating a suite of tests (using Geb/Spock) for a web site. In one of them, the element I want to access is on the top of the page, so, to make sure that is visible, I want to scroll to the top of the page.

The command I am using is:

> browser.js.exec('window.scrollTo(0, 0);')

or variations of it like

> js.exec('window.scrollTo(0, 0);')

or other alternative like:

> js.exec('window.scrollBy(0, -250);')

None of them makes the page scroll up, and when executing I get the following error (it is the only error, no other feedback). The error message using the other options listed above is identical (other than the command itself):

```
    Condition not satisfied:
    browser.js.exec('window.scrollTo(0, 0);')
    |       |  |
    |       |  null
    |       geb.js.JavascriptInterface@4019094f
    geb.Browser@3dcac33e
        at UserCreatesCompany.Go to Home Page and click on the log to
GitHub button as user User1(UserCreatesCompany.groovy:170)
```

I can not interpret the message that 'exec' is null. What exactly it means?
To make things more interesting, at the end of this script I am running the following cleanup procedure

```
    js.exec('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    DeleteButton.click()
    $("button",'data-automation-id':"button-modal-yes").click()
}
```

and that works well: the page scrolls down. So, does not seem a problem about some missing library.
Any suggestion of what I may be doing wrong?

The version of the different components I am using is:

```
    groovyVersion = '2.5.4'
    gebVersion = '2.3'
    seleniumVersion = '3.141.59'
    chromeDriverVersion = '2.45'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not need to ever manually scroll the page to make elements visible - Selenium WebDriver which is underpinning Geb will do that for you automatically as soon as you start interacting (clicking, setting value, etc) with content.

Secondly, the failure you are getting is a failed assertion coming from a statement in an automatically asserted (`then:` or `expect:`) Spock block. It feels to me that you don't understand a concept which is core to Spock and therefore you should read [about it in the manual](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/spock_primer.html#_blocks) first. It should make the failure you're getting clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Clearly: I was not fully aware of the different constrains the different blocks impose on what is executable or not. The manual is pretty clear once you have stumbled!

I am intrigued by your first assertion pointing that Selenium WebDriver will move to the element as soon as I interact with it. That was my understanding but it was not working. I made sure the element in question had a unique identifier, but still, it was not able to found it if the element had to be found by scrolling up. On the other hand it worked smoothly when locating the element WebDriver scrolled the page down.

Thanks again for the explanation. I have learn something new today!